# How to generate Postgres tables correctly from spring boot application?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

i am developing a RESTFUL API using spring-boot for a future Angular Front-End. i am having this problem with creating my entities into postgres tables.

connectivity with the database was checked and all is fine. using mvn clean install & mvn spring-boot run commands generate normal tomcat deployment without any errors. however no tables are create

here's my code: 
entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "question_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "question_generator",
            sequenceName = "question_sequence",
            initialValue = 1000
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Question() {

    }





}
```

application.propreties:

```
# ===============================
# DATABASE CONNECTION
# ===============================

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


# Fix Postgres JPA Error:
# Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

and here's my repo:

```
import model.Question;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i was able to resolve this issue by changing the entity package and made it visible to the app. now it works perfectly fine.
the main package name is: com.testAppBlaBla
entities's package should be com.testAppBlaBla.model

otherwise the entity won't be generated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had the same problem and then, I moved my entity to a subpackage of the package containing the DemoApplication class and it finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `create` value.